# Method to copy to a pre-existing file without declaring a new file?

Tags: java, file, amazon-s3, inputstream

Essentially I have an application that needs to pull a .txt file from an S3 bucket and write it's contents into a local text file so that another class can pull the data and update the associated jFrame.

Before this snippet of code I have been deleting after use, however if I need to refresh the jFrame a preexistingfileexception as expected.  The whole limiting factor is the fact that to manipulate "input.txt" I need to re-declare it as a file in each statement.

I have tried using filewriter and many other copy methods but end up with the same issue everytime.  Trying to delete to the path the file is located, circumventing the need declare the file name leads to a file in use exception.  Ultimately this will be pushed to a web application and caching will solve all of my issues but for now I just would really like to have the local application running properly for demonstration.

Really anyway to copy to a file or manipulate a file without `new File("input.txt")` would be great.

```
s3object.getObjectMetadata().getContentType());  
InputStream input = s3object.getObjectContent();                
Files.copy(input, new File("input.txt").toPath());
```

Comment: Disregard first line, that is part of a SOUT command for debugging purposes.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Quick tip: the less text you write to describe your problem, the easier it is for everyone. This seems like a wall of text to actually get to the problem.

Comment: Declaring `new File("input.txt")` has exactly nothing to do with `PreexistingFileException`. Unclear what you're asking.